# Multiple asterisk servers SIP or PJSIP realtime

Tags: asterisk, sip, pjsip

I have two Asterisk(sip1 and sip2) with one realtime MySQL DB. So any user can register on sip1 or sip2. No problems with outgoing calls to other providers. 
The issue I’m having is calling across servers. Say 101 calls 102 - where 101 is registered to sip1 and 102 is on sip2. 
When use SIP:
In sip.conf

```
[general] 
rtsavesysname=yes
```

In sip_peers DB table field "regserver" is filled correctly. But don't understand how can I Dial to each peer
It would be really great if 101 can call to 102 across server.

Maybe it's easier on PJSIP?

I'm using last asterisk version from git by 13/03/2019

Answer (score 0):

You should use ENUM or DUNDi, not realtime peer if you trying to find on which server your extension.